# Bing Code search not working when Resharper is installed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, visual-studio-extensions

Wanted to try the [Bing Code search](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1166718-a2d9-4a48-a5fd-504ff4ad1b65) extension for VS2013, but it did not work since I had Resharper installed on my machine.

ReSharper overrides the Visual Studio Intellisense for it’s additional functionality and Bing's code search doesn't come up in the Intellisense.

How to get this working together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created a keyboard shortcut to launch the Bing search rather than relying on the intellisense to pop up.

**Go to** 
Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

Assign a new shortcut for **Tools.LaunchSnippetSearch** - e.g. Ctrl+1

Comment: not quite as integrated as the examples show, but this works, thanks!  Also note that by default it appears to have an alt+a key binding

Comment: I go to my VS2013 Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and there is not a shortcut listed for Tolls.LaunchSnippetSearch.  I have Re-sharper installed and the Bing developer assistant.  Any ideas??